# hibernate can basedao has multiple sessionFactory if can't how to handle multiple datasources

Tags: hibernate

i met a problem ,how to handle multiple sessionFactory in baseDao?

```
public class BaseDao<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IBaseDao<T> {


//注入SessionFactory
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
public void setSuperSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}

@Resource(name="secondSessionFactory")
public void setSuper2SessionFactory(SessionFactory secondSessionFactory){
    super.setSessionFactory(secondSessionFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approache to create different session factories is to use different *.cfg.xml *.cfg.xml configuration files. And then use

> ```
> Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("*.cfg.xml");
> ```

In the XML file use the following code

> ```
>  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>        destroy-method="close"   
>        driverClassName="***"
>        url="jdbc:sqlserver://${FirstDB_HosName}
>           \${FirstDB_instanceName}:${FirstDB_PortNumber};databaseName= 
>            ${FirstDB_DatabaseName}; username=${FirstDB_UserName}; 
>            password=${FirstDB_Password};" />
>   <bean id="sessionFactory" 
>         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
>      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
>      <property name="configLocation">
>        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
>      </property>
>      <property name="hibernateProperties">
>        <props>  
>          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
>          <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
>          <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
>        </props>
>     </property>   
> </bean>     
>
>
> <bean id="seconddataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>        destroy-method="close"   
>        driverClassName="***"
>        url="jdbc:sqlserver://${SecondDB_HosName}
>           \${SecondDB_instanceName}:${SecondDB_PortNumber};databaseName= 
>            ${SecondDB_DatabaseName}; username=${SecondDB_UserName}; 
>            password=${SecondDB_Password};" />
>   <bean id="secondsessionFactory" 
>         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
>      <property name="dataSource" ref="seconddataSource" />
>      <property name="configLocation">
>        <value>classpath:hibernate-second.cfg.xml</value>
>      </property>
>      <property name="hibernateProperties">
>        <props>
>          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
>          <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
>          <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
>        </props>
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

In the DAO, use @Qualifier annotation to wire the 2 session factories

> ```
> @Autowired
> @Qualifier(value="sessionFactory")
> private SessionFactory sessionFactory;  
>
> @Autowired
> @Qualifier(value="secondDBSessionFactory")
> private SessionFactory SecondSessionFactory;
> ```